# How can I tell Perl's prove utility to ignore certain tests?

Tags: perl, perl-prove

Currently I run `prove` like this:

```
prove -v -r .
```

Is there a way to *exclude* files using regex? I could not see that in `perldoc prove` or the output of `prove -H`.

Comment: There's not, but I swear I saw an article a few weeks ago, maybe on http://blogs.perl.org, where someone had worked on making this possible.  I'm looking in my @perlbuzz Twitter archives and not seeing it there.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *usually* do something like this:

```
$ find t/ -name '*.t' ! -name '*timeout*' | xargs prove -l
```

(skips slow timeout tests)

Comment: Awesome! (though I would suggest adding a \ to `*`s in the command)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this by using a  sub-directory :

```
$ tree t/
t/
├── 01_tests.t
├── 02_tests.t
├── 03_tests.t
└── ignored
    └── 01_ignored.t
```

Then I do this to execute the normal tests:

```
$ prove -v t/*.t
t/01_tests.t ........ ok
t/02_tests.t ........ ok
t/03_tests.t ........ ok
Result: PASS
```

And this to execute the *ignored* tests in another context:

```
$ prove -v t/ignored/
t/ignored/01_ignored.t ........ ok
Result: PASS
```

Simple and efficient solution if your tests are not already stored in different sub-directories.

For making it easier to use, and document how to run the tests, I usually put those in a `Makefile`.